# Is there any scripting support for VS Debugger, something similar to GDB's scripting?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, scripting

I'm asking to script the Visual Studio Debugger itself, like some statements for "set breakpoint", "continue", "step over", "print variable" and so on. In other words, the counterpart of [GDB's scripting](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-119-gdb-scripting-part-1). I've googled keywords like "visual studio debugger scripting" but got nothing useful. Is it true that VS Debugger just doesn't support scripting?

I am NOT asking to debug some scripting language such as Javascript or VBscript in VS.

Answer (score 0):

[EnvDTE.Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.debugger?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) interface provides access to breakpoints and have Go, StepOver, GetExpression methods.

You can call it from your Visual Studio extension or use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) for lightweight scripting (see for example [Remove all disabled breakpoints in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342545/remove-all-disabled-breakpoints-in-visual-studio/65352907#65352907)).